# AngularJS - controller and factory - where am I going wrong at include/inject functions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I'm new to Angular and cannot pinpoint where I am going wrong. I'm just trying to simply inject my factory into my controller, reference said: "Cannot read property 'validar' of undefined". I have two files, ServiceUtil.js where have a service and CentroCustoCtrl.js where I'm trying to use service's function.

The function at ServiceUtil.js:

```
 (function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('Services', [])
  .service('ValidarFormulario', [function () {

      this.validar = function (form) {
          var valido = true;
         //code
          }
          return valido;
      }
  }]);

})();
```

And CentroCustoCtrl.js

```
(function () {
 'use strict';

var app = angular.module("start", ['AxelSoft', 'ngLocalize',
       'ngLocalize.Config', 'mvComponentes','Services'])
       .value('localeConf', {
               basePath: '../Scripts/Locales', ...
 ...
 });
 app.controller('CentroCustoCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'ValidarFormulario', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, ValidarFormulario) {
   $scope.Salvar = function () {
    if (ValidarFormulario.validar(document.getElementsByTagName('input'))) { ...// Cannot read property 'validar' of undefined

  );
```

I tried with factory , but not worked too:

```
angular.module('Services', [])
.factory('ValidarFormulario', [function () {

    return{
        validar : function (form) {
            var valido = true;
           //code
                }
            }
            return valido;
          }
      }
   }]);

})();
```

Please, I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Remove this keyword while you using ValidarFormulario

Comment: @VinitSolanki as he is adding function to service, `this` keyword is correct..

Comment: Ys you are right pankaj, thats why i give u upvote.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you had wrong dependency sequence inside DI inline array, basically they are mismatching in number and their sequences

```
app.controller('CentroCustoCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'ValidarFormulario',
    //removed $rootScope, $timeout which wasn't used.
    function ($scope, $http, ValidarFormulario) {
```

OR either way you could just add the dependency inside array, if they are really gonna used inside controller like below

```
app.controller('CentroCustoCtrl', ['$scope','$http','$rootScope','$timeout','ValidarFormulario', 
    function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, ValidarFormulario) {
```

Comment: Thank you @PankajParkar, the 1st solution worked nice. Good job.

Comment: @EduardoAndrade Ideally both should work.. glad to know that.. Thanks :-)  do accept answer, if it does solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the below line of code

```
app.controller('CentroCustoCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'ValidarFormulario', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, ValidarFormulario) {
```

to

```
app.controller('CentroCustoCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', '$timeout',  'ValidarFormulario', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, ValidarFormulario) {
```

This should work.

Comment: adding answer with same content covered by other after 15-20 mins, doesn't make sense..

Comment: You are welcome @Eduardo Andrade. Please upvote answers if you find them useful.

Comment: You're right. I'm on mobile and the answers hasn't refreshed, so sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Well, also I've saw that your controller injections are wrong. You have:

```
App.controller('CentroCustoCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'ValidarFormulario', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, ValidarFormulario)
```

And you should have:

```
app.controller('CentroCustoCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'ValidarFormulario', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope,$timeout, ValidarFormulario)
```

Injectors on "[ ]" must mach with  function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

When you set a module the syntax is:

```
angular.module('Services', [ here injections ])
```

But when you get a module to use it, syntax must be:

```
angular.module('Services')
```